# SharpMap System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, sharpmap

I am using SharpMap within a window service. I am using the library to generate a map and then create an image out of it and add it to an Excel file. The code runs within a Quartz.net task.

The error happens when I call `SharpMap.Map.GetMap()` and crushes my service (see error report and stack call below).

This only happens every now and then (maybe issues with data?). Also note, I had some issues with working with the map so I put some delay (`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);`) just before calling the function.

I am generating several such images and the error (last time it occurred) was after a few (~10) iterations. In order not to recreate and format the "static layers" of the map (`SharpMap.Map`) each time I just add and remove the "dynamic" layers and resize some features in each iteration.

Is there a way to find what the cause of the error?

Is there a way to gracefully handle such exception?

### The Windows CMS error report + stack trace:

> Application: NePTune.WinService.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>
> Stack:

```
at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdipPathIterNextSubpathPath(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32 ByRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Boolean ByRef) 
at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdipPathIterNextSubpathPath(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32 ByRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Boolean ByRef) 
at System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPathIterator.NextSubpath(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath, Boolean ByRef) 
at SharpMap.Rendering.Symbolizer.WarpPathToPath.Warp(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath, Boolean, Single) 
at SharpMap.Rendering.Symbolizer.WarpPathToPath.DrawString(System.Drawing.Graphics, System.Drawing.Pen, System.Drawing.Brush, System.String, System.Drawing.FontFamily, Int32, Single, System.Drawing.StringFormat, Boolean, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath) 
at SharpMap.Layers.LabelLayer.Render(System.Drawing.Graphics, SharpMap.Map) 
at SharpMap.Map.RenderMap(System.Drawing.Graphics) 
at SharpMap.Map.GetMap() 
at NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.UlInterferenceReportWriter.CreateClusterMap(System.Collections.Generic.List1<NePTune.Data.SectorGeoDetails>, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2<Int32,Double>, Int32, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1<NePTune.Data.SectorGeoDetails>, Boolean) 
at NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.UlInterferenceReportWriter.CreateInterferenceClusterWorksheets(OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage, System.Collections.Generic.List1<NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.UlInterferenceCluster>, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2<Int32,NePTune.Data.SectorGeoDetails>, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2<Int32,NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.CellMeasurementList>) 
at NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.UlInterferenceReportWriter.CreateReport(System.Collections.Generic.List1<NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.CellUlInterferenceResults>, System.Collections.Generic.List1<NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.UlInterferenceCluster>, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2<Int32,NePTune.Data.SectorGeoDetails>, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2<Int32,NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.CellMeasurementList>) 
at NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.UlInterferenceDriver.Execute(NePTune.Common.Configuration.GlobalConfiguration, NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.UlInterference.UlInterferenceConfiguration) 
at NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.AlgorithmJobs.UlInterferenceJob.Execute(NePTune.Common.Configuration.GlobalConfiguration, NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.Common.IAlgorithmConfiguration, System.String, System.String, System.String) 
at NePTune.Logic.Algorithms.AlgorithmJobs.UlInterferenceJob.Execute(Quartz.IJobExecutionContext) 
at Quartz.Core.JobRunShell.Run() 
at Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool+WorkerThread.Run() 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was discussing this in the SharpMap project page on CodePlex (https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) and over there they suggested to clone the map before calling to get map.

I changed the code a little to make a clone of the map in each iteration before adding my "dynamic layers" and then calling `GetMap()`.

This prevents the access violation.

See more details here:
https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/discussions/558218